# Find words by characters inside string

Tags: java, regex

is it possible using java to get words by characters from string using java API or regular expressions?

For example I have string :

```
`A broken friendship may be soldered, but will never be sound.`
```

and want to get all words that include `so` (*soldered* and *sound*) and replace them with 
`<b>soldered</b>` and `<b>sound</b>`

Thanks!

Comment: YES. string.indexOf() is your simplest solution. string.replace(), string.replaceAll() etc. can also be used.

Comment: "is it possible [...]?" Yes, of course!

Comment: you can do that using two function first .split(" ") or the second is .substring()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple regex replace will do it for you:

```
String sentence = "A broken friendship may be soldered, but will never be sound.";
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]*so[a-zA-Z]*)", "<b>$1</b>");
```

Here using the regex it is picking the word which is around the alphabet and then capture this as a group(`$1`). And then wrapping it around  html tag.

Comment: one little question. how can I using regex replace only first word (soldered by <b>soldered</b>)?

Comment: @hard-code That case use `sentence.replaceFirst()` instead of `sentence.replaceAll()`.